# try to run recursion function in python but it will retun non for v1 and v2

Tags: python, django, function, recursion, recursive-query

```py
v1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'this', 'that', 'is', 'of']
v2 = {"Hamza": 1, "Kashif": 2, "Ali": 3}
v3 = "I love pakistan."

def rec(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for i in value:
         rec(i)
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for k, v in value.items():
        rec(k)
    else:
        return str(value).upper()

print(rec(v1))
print(rec(v2))
print(rec(v3))
```

kindly solve this problem because i am getting None when call V! and V2

Comment: yes in each if its returning None when its iterate on V1 List and V2 Dictionary and at the end i want input in upper case

Comment: You're not returning the recursive calls

Comment: ok would you please tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: @DS_Hamza instead of doing `rec(i)` do `return rec(i)`. Also please format your code properly, the indentations are all over the place.

Comment: thanks @Sayse got it problem  solved :) have a nice day

Comment: i am new at stackoverflow i will improve thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're after.

```
v1 = ['hi', 'hello', ['this', 'that'], 'is', 'of']
v2 = {"Hamza": 1, "Kashif": 2, "Ali": 3}
v3 = "I love pakistan."


def rec(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for i in range(len(value)):
            value[i] = rec(value[i])
        return value
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        d = dict()
        for k in value:
            d[rec(k)] = value[k]
        return d
    else:
        return str(value).upper()


print(rec(v1))
print(rec(v2))
print(rec(v3))
```